# How do you integrate APM server monitoring with NextJS server?

Tags: next.js

I want to integrate server monitoring system like DataDog that implements APM standards. I want to achieve this without using the custom server like Express or Koa, just using the out-of-box NextJS server. My NextJS server is only being used for pages, not APIs. It would help if NextJS allows us to insert middleware for all requests. However it doesn't look like that's an option. Do you know a good way to do this?

Comment: did you find the answers to your question ?

Comment: Not yet. The only solution I find on the Internet is to use a custom server. We ended up using Koa. But custom servers can't be deployed using Vercel so it's a deal breaker.

Comment: I just found this (actually it was yesterday), dunno if this would help you, but it is worth a try: https://jake.tl/notes/2021-04-04-nextjs-preload-hack
Lemme know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. log everything through some DataDog supported library ([see full list here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/compatibility/nodejs/#logger-compatibility)). I would recommend having some `logger` wrapper service in your codebase and reuse it everywhere
2. make sure to have your logger library (e.g. winston) listed under project's root `node_modules` so dd agent can find it and instrument it
3. set env variable `DD_LOGS_INJECTION=true`
4. run your app using [node --require](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_r_require_module) via command line like so `node --require dd-trace/init ./node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start --port <port>`, [see more info here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/automatic_instrumentation/dd_libraries/nodejs/#adding-the-tracer-via-command-line-arguments)
5. if you happen to use supported libraries (like `axios`) to communicate with other services - that will be traced automatically as well